# Eliminate prefixes to tables in Lua

Tags: lua

```
function1
   weaponsList.earth = {weapon_type='regular',fireTime=0, fireRate=0.7, speed = 250, img = nil}
end
```

can you do something like this to access a sub member.

```
  "using weaponsList,earth"
     fireTime = 2
     fireRate = 2
     speed = 2
   end
```

instead of having to do this

```
   weaponsList.earth.fireTime = 2
   weaponsList.earth.fireRate = 2
   weaponsList.earth.speed = 2
```

Not sure what this is called but I've seen this in C or C++.Is there a way to do this in Lua and what is it called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the following, but be careful.  Setting _ENV to your table means that, within that scope, you can't see outside the table.

```
do local _ENV = weaponsList.earth
  fireTime = 2
  fireRate = 2
  speed = 2
end
```

Another, possibly better method is simply:

```
do local e = weaponsList.earth
  e.fireTime = 2
  e.fireRate = 2
  e.speed = 2
end
```

Assigning a nested table to a local variable before doing multiple manipulations is actually an optimization in the base Lua implementation, since it will not need to dereference the outer tables in each usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify a table into a smaller variable.

```
t = weaponsList.earth
```

Now t.firerate is the same as weaponsList.earth.firerate. Adjusting the values of t will also update the original table.

Not sure if this will help but you can also save all the variables from a table into globals.

```
for k,v in pairs(table) do
    _G[k] = v
end
```

Edit: Thanks for the correction lhf

Comment: Altering `t.speed` *will* alter `weaponsList.earth.speed`.